# Python uri online judge

Tags: python

Leia um valor inteiro X. Em seguida apresente os 6 valores ímpares consecutivos a partir de X, um valor por linha, inclusive o X ser for o caso.

Entrada: a entrada será um valor inteiro positivo.

Saída: a saída será uma sequência de seis números ímpares.

```
x=int(input())
impar=0
while(impar<6):
 x=x+1
 impar=+1
 if(x%2 != 0):
   print('%d' %x)
```

Como faço para sair da impressão infinita e imprimir apenas 6?

Answer (score 4):

O principal problema nesse seu código:

```
x=int(input())
impar=0
while(impar<6):
 x=x+1
 impar=+1
 if(x%2 != 0):
   print('%d' %x)
```

É que você confundiu o operador para "somar valor na variável" - que seria `+=` com `=+`. Como Python ignora espaços entre operadores matemáticos, a sequência `impar=+1` significa simplesmente  `impar = +1`. Ou seja, a sua variável que seria o contador fica sempre valendo "1", e portanto, sempre menor que 6 - e  a condição do `while` sempre é verdadeira.

Na linha de cima dessas, você colocou por extenso `x = x + 1` - isso sim, pega o valor anterior de x, soma 1, e atribui esse novo resultado ao `x`. O operador `+=` usado corretamente faz exatamente isso - então as duas linhas poderiam ser `x += 1` e `impar += 1` (ou `x = x + 1` e `impar = impar + 1`)

Esse não é o único erro nesse código - se arrumar isso, ele deixa de ser infinito, e talvez você consiga arrumar o restante, analizando os novos resultados. Se você não se importa, vou encerrar a resposta por aqui, e deixar um pouco do desafio de volta pra você.
Se continuar precisando de ajuda, indique nos comentários, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Teu programa está praticamente pronto, só necessitando pequenos ajustes que acho que tu deve ter feito, mas em todo o caso "aí vai" (com os números que testei funcionou):

```
x = int(input())
impar = 0
while(impar<11):
 x = x + 1
 impar += 1
 if(x%2 != 0):
  print('%d' %x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão ser refere ao problema de número **"1070"**, cujo título é **"Seis Números Ímpares"** disponibilizado por **"Uri Online Judge"** (Maratona Online de Programação).

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1070) a íntegra do enunciado.

Nesta questão é solicitado ao `usuário` que digite um valor `inteiro X`. Em seguida, o programa calculará os **PRÓXIMOS** `6` números impares consecutivos, a partir do número digitado `X`.

Nesta questão devemos **OBSERVAR** o **valor de x**. Caso o valor de `x` for ímpar, ele também **deverá ser listado na saída**. Caso contrário **não deverá ser listado na saída**.

Pois bem, para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o laço de repetição **while** ou **for**.

Para resolver esta questão utilizando o **while**, podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
x = int(input())
impar = 0
while impar < 12:
    impar += 1
    if x % 2 != 0:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

E, para resolver esta questão utilizando o **for**, podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
X = int(input())
for c in range(X, (X + 12)):
    if c % 2 != 0:
        print(c)
```

Observe que em ambos códigos podemos notar o valor **12** em evidência.

**Então, porque utilizar o valor 12 no código?**

O valor **12** é igual ao produto entre a **quantidade** de valores a serem exibidos e o **passo** do range. Se a quantidade de valores as serem exibidas é **6** e o passo do range é **2** - pois a ocorrência de cada número ímpar no conjunto dos números inteiros é de **2 em 2** - então, **6 x 2 = 12**.

Quando executamos qualquer um dos códigos, recebemos uma tela **preta** com o cursor do mouse **piscando** no canto superior esquerdo da tela. Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar `enter`. A partir de então, o laço de repetição executará as interações possíveis e, com a ajuda do bloco `if`, será verificado se cada valor temporário do laço é ímpar. Caso positivo, a função `print()` exibirá o respectivo valor.

Estes códigos já foram `testados`, `submetidos` e devidamente `aprovados` no site `Uri`, sob linguagem de programação **Python 3**.